# Create a dropdownlist from datatable

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I want to create a dropdownlist based on a table with values from my Table_Services anda save in my Table_Status Services

[image: IMG]

at the moment I have this:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => @item.Status, new { @class = "Status", disabled = true }) //from my Table_Status
```

i try to create a list, but without success :(

My model:

```
public List<Table_Services> ServicesList { get; set; }
```

Controller:

```
OrderViewModel model = new OrderViewModel
        {
            ServicesList = db.Table_Services.ToList()
        };
```

View:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => @item.Status, new SelectList(Model.ServicesList, "Services", "Select", new { @class="statusselect",disabled = true })
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

You missed dataValueField on Html.DropDownListFor

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => @item.Status, new SelectList(Model.ServicesList, "ID", "Services", "Select One"), new { @class = "form-control col-md-12" })
```